# How to show a context menu on right click in Qt5.5 qml TreeView

Tags: qt, treeview, qml, qt-quick

I want to show a context menu when right-clicking on Qt5.5 qml TreeView item, but it has clicked signal. How to show a context menu on right click?

```
    TreeView {
        id: tree_view
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: tree_model
        headerVisible: false
        backgroundVisible: false

        TableViewColumn {
            role: "display"
        }

        onClicked: {
            console.log("clicked", index)
        }

        onDoubleClicked: isExpanded(index) ? collapse(index) : expand(index)
    }
```

Comment: Just ran into the same problem. I think the solution is currently a hack with MouseArea and bypassing the signals.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually quite easy, you just need a MouseArea configured to accept only right click events, and it won't interfere with the mouse handling performed by the TreeView itself:

```
TreeView {
    id: tree_view
    anchors.fill: parent
    model: tree_model

    TableViewColumn {
        role: "display"
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        acceptedButtons: Qt.RightButton
        onClicked: {
            var index = parent.indexAt(mouse.x, mouse.y)
            if (index.valid) {
                console.log("show context menu for row: " + index.row)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you simply define your menu somewhere and use the `popup` method to show it? That method open the menu near to the mouse cursor, so to the right position.

Of course, you have to define your `itemDelegate` as well and let the event flows out of your item if needed (do not consume it).

The documentation for the `clicked` signal of a `TreeView` explicitly refers to the item delegate to consume those events, so I guess this is the intended approach.